# Typescript - How to return an object with a property removed where the property is given as a string

Tags: string, typescript, object, properties

How in Typescript can I write a function where I can pass in any object and a string property to be removed and get back a new object with all the original properties except for the one that should be removed?

This is my attempt but every suggestion I have seen does not work for me.

```
type ObjectKeys<T> = 
  T extends object ? (keyof T)[] :
  T extends number ? [] :
  T extends Array<any> | string ? string[] :
  never;

interface ObjectConstructor {
  keys<T>(o: T): ObjectKeys<T>
}

type Person = {
  name: string, age: number, id: number,
}
let me: Person

me = {name: 'Paul',age:32,id:1}

function test(obj: object , propToRemove : string) :object {
  let rest :object
  ({ [propToRemove]:, ...rest} = obj)
  return rest
}

test(me,'age')
```

Answer (score 2):

The function, let's call it `omit()`, should be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in both the type of the object `T` and the type of the key `K` you want to remove.

In this case, the return type of the function is either `Omit<T, K>` using the [`Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys), *or* it is `Omit<T, K> & Partial<Record<K, never>>` (using the [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) utility types.

The type `Omit<T, K>` just means that the object is like `T` but is not known to have a property at key `K`, whereas the more complex intersection type means the object is like `T` but that it explicitly lacks any property but `undefined` at key `K`.  The difference here looks like:

```
type Person = {
    name: string, age: number, id: number,
}

type OmittedAgePerson = Omit<Person, "age">;
/* type OmittedAgePerson = {
    name: string;
    id: number;
} */

type ExplictlyUndefinedAgePerson = Omit<Person, "age"> & Partial<Record<"age", never>>;
/* equivalent to type ExplictlyUndefinedAgePerson = {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    age?: undefined;
} */
```

I'm going to assume you need the simpler one, but keep in mind that `T` is assignable to `Omit<T, K>` (e.g., a value of type `Person` can be assigned to a variable of type `{name: string, id: number}`)... so be sure to check this against your use cases.

Anyway, here's one possible implementation:

```
function omit<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): Omit<T, K> {
    const o: Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>> = { ...obj };
    delete o[key];
    return o;
}
```

I am explicitly annotating the new object `o` as being like `T` but having an optional property at key `K`.  This allows the `delete` operator to work.  Let's test it:

```
let me: Person = { name: 'Paul', age: 32, id: 1 }

const miniMe = omit(me, 'age');
// const miniMe: Pick<Person, "name" | "id">

console.log(JSON.stringify(miniMe)); // {"name":"Paul","id":1}
console.log(miniMe.id.toFixed(2)); // 1.00
console.log(miniMe.name.toUpperCase()); // PAUL
console.log(miniMe.age.toFixed(2)); // error!
// --------------> ~~~
// Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Pick<Person, "name" | "id">'.
```

Looks good to me.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHAtjKAeAKogpgDylzABMBnZAIwCtdoAaRAaT0OPMQGtcBPOYRFgB8ACjg0AXIMbceUpgEopAeTSYsjJkMQBvAFCJDiCAjJRkKtdk3aAZIgAKAQwBOsJwBsMDmBE7XmIW0AXl1EADpI8WpEAF8AbgMjElwPXCJkAG1ZAF1Eo0QXdJAXJDhE2IM9PSgeAAdcR1wXMgREUP0CsCcUXCkzFxgwAHNGJ2G+xDAQFEpmxhgSKWnZ+b1KmvrG1XQiEgBBCYdm1qRQncxjloRGACJx3FuhRIB6ACpEWobEC73D3Cup3auiShm6vX6UEGI3yRkWyxmcxcFUQbxe1S+jQAovg6h5fFAPDwAKqkXDAIa4A5HE5tc5WQE3RD3CZPRD2ZxuGCeDAAJTocBcJAwLMejDAuAAbs0gogXi8CERSBQhsBmj9EAB+MKZByIIZcXj8H45FS6nJxRDLKXNV4fTGIHF4glE0kpCkS6kA2lnEFdHqTAZDYawwzwqaI22gxAPTVScDuykkFFo6p6NLmCFNa5gPS9YE6KYBqQAcmcIA8JbGEykAGYAEwLJaIACMcTTJjAZkQaDAMAAso1Qqh0CJeowSw8SwpXi9jKZM0MB5MfH5vD67uDHogAD7MxZPaqd1ppcIeODDEQAKQAysoAHLhIMjGDAHhjpeDhQzuVznS3LdbgkW5yw8W56FuA8JBbSpjzgU9z0vXtl3CRZwigOAADEYHwKkRHrb94l-VtwgABlIvQ4IQi8Pz7Qdwi3dC4GJOoGhcABhJwyFwERCOIhx9mJAAZSjTHg3Azxo5D6IeJjsNwkh8L4+U8BcFxBQAQj0FSAFo9P0gyDO0AA-UztLnBx1LY2pEEnCYS0QEg4FwCgwDgcwCBgbs2gdMtfH8RkwE3ANbl3fcSCeEtwiAA)

Comment: Excellent, as always!

Comment: Many thanks for an excellent answer. It definitely works. One question though. Other posts seem to advise against the use of delete because of immutability. Your code seems fine to me as the only thing having something deleted from it is a constant that is local to the function. However, I have seen other examples that use Deconstruction to split the object into the desired key and the rest of the keys. The example I saw was something like ({[key]:, ...rest}) = obj. Is there a way to do something like this, or is it not worth bothering? (That particular example didn't work)

Comment: Sure, you could do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/rw2Lbm) if you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer does not quite work in practice. It is OK with a string literal but when the parameter is defined as a :string the compiler gives an error Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"age" | "name" | "id"'. To work around this I assigned the key to an any and then it could be passed.

`const sKey:string  = 'age';
  const aKey:any = sKey; 
  const minime = Omit(me,aKey)`
I know just about enough about Typescript to know that any solution that involves using Any is probably not the best but it gets around the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the `omit` function:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys

Comment: Thanks for the link Chris,